# Multiple websocket servers via APIM?

Tags: wso2

Generally we have APIM point to a single host in DNS.  We then use DNS to resolve the host to multiple hosts using round robin.

```
         /--host1
---[APIM]---host2
         \--host3
```

Will this work with websockets?  To be more clear, if we have a single host setup in APIM as a websocket server that actually resolves to 3 different hosts via DNS, will this work with WSO2 APIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work. But the load balancing will happen at the connection level, but not at the frame level. That means if you have 3 clients connecting, those 3 will stick to each host.